# vectorized minimization and root finding in jax

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, vectorization, jax

I have a family of functions parameterized by `args`

```
f(x, args)
```

and want to determine the minimum of `f` over `x` for `N = 1000` values of `args`. I have access to both the function and its derivative. My first attempt was to loop through the different values of `args` and use a scipy.optimizer at each iteration, but it takes too long. I believe the operations can be sped up with vectorization. My next attempt was to use `jax.vmap` inside a `jax.scipy.optimize.minimize` or `jaxopt.ScipyMinimize`, but I can't seem to pass more than one value for `args`.

Alternatively, I can code my own vectorized optimization method, e.g. bisection, where by vectorized I mean doing operations on arrays for a fixed number of iterations and not stopping early if one of the optimization problems has reached a certain error tolerance level early. I was hoping to use some optimized off-shelf algorithm.

I was hoping to use some already optimized, off-the-shelf algorithm if an implementation is available in jax.[this](https://github.com/google/jax/issues/5732) thread is related, but the `args` are not changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function to find the minimum given particular `args`, and then wrap it in `jax.vmap` to automatically vectorize it. For example:

```py
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax.scipy import optimize

def f(x, args):
  a, b = args
  return jnp.sum(a + (x - b) ** 2)

def find_min(a, b):
  x0 = jnp.array([1.0])
  args = (a, b)
  return optimize.minimize(f, x0, (args,), method="BFGS")

a_grid, b_grid = jnp.meshgrid(jnp.arange(5.0), jnp.arange(5.0))

results = jax.vmap(find_min)(a_grid.ravel(), b_grid.ravel())

print(results.success)
# [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
#   True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
#   True]

print(results.x.T)
# [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2.
#   3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 4. 4. 4. 4. 4.]]
```